# SQL UPDATE CLASS_NUMBER BY NAME ORDER

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I dont know if i choose the right title for my question.
I have that table like this in my database.

```
NAME                                               class_num
-------------------------------------------------- --------
name1                                               2
name2                                               4
name3                                               1
```

And what I want to do is:
Update the class_num to be in order like the name. The result from what I want is that:

```
    NAME                                            class_num
-------------------------------------------------- ---------
name1                                                1
name2                                                2
name3                                                3
```

Is any way to do that with a QUERY? 
Or I need to do from C# code?

Sorry my english, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why you want to do so? An id is a technical value.

Comment: Maybe the ID is not the best example, let me change.

Comment: Can it be assumed that there is a primary key on this table which is unique? Or is name unique?

Comment: What database are you using?  You should tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: Im using SQL SERVER, The primary key is the ID but im not showing in that query

Comment: [Beginner SQL Tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm)

Comment: Just a question. This `class_num` is used by some other table to establish a relationship with this table ?

Comment: No, im  using student_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use an updatable CTE (or subquery):

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by name) as new_class_num
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set class_num = new_class_num;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

1. that your ID field is not an IDENTITY field, and can be updated
2. That your Name column holds unique values (there are no duplicate names)

You can do something like this (example in T-SQL for SQL Server):

```
-- Select all Names in alphabetical order, and give them a row number
INSERT INTO #NewIdTable
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ASC) as Row, Name
FROM MyTable

-- Update the ID's using the RowNumber as a new ID.
UPDATE MyTable
SET Id = Row
FROM #NewIdTable INNER JOIN MyTable ON #NewIdTable.Name = MyTable.Name
```

Edit:  Looks like you clarified in the comments that your class_num column is a key.  Therefore you will have to adjust this method.  Try updating "Name" by joining on the row-number instead, if your ID's are sequential.  Alternately, you could drop the key constraint temporarily, update the ID's, and create the key again.  Another method might be to simply create a new table with IDENTITY INSERT ON and copy the names over to it in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You can delete your table that query

```
"TRUNCATE TABLE table_name"
```

And later, you can create your table again with that query

```
"CREATE TABLE table_name
(
column_name1 data_type(size),
column_name2 data_type(size),
column_name3 data_type(size),
....
);"
```